# Passing private member pointer to Unmanaged Function C++/CLI

Tags: .net, pointers, c++-cli, wrapper

I am having trouble passing an unmanaged pointer (stored as a member in a managed wrapper) to an unmanaged function that requires a double pointer (pointer to the stored unmanaged pointer).  This problem is illustrated below:

I have a wrapper for an unmanaged C structure declared below:

```
   public ref class MyStructWrapper
    {
    private:
    myStruct *_rto;
    public:

    MyStructWrapper()
    {
        _rto = new myStruct();
    }

    // read-only property
    public property RTO{
       myStruct * get(){return _rto;}
    }
    }
```

I need to call a function from a C Dll:

```
// alters data based on data in "SomeotherStructWrapper"(which consequently holds a 
// SomeOtherStruct* ).

int SomeOtherStructWrapper::AlterMyStruct(myStructWrapper^ myObj)
{

    // unmanaged function in C DLL
    pin_ptr<myStruct> ptr = myObj->RTO;
    AlterMyStructUnmanaged(&ptr,&someOtherStructStoredMemberPtr);


}
```

The goal is to alter the data that myObj->RTO points to...  Unfortunately, this compiles and runs and alters the data behind ptr, but the actual data I need to be altered in myObj is not.

EDIT:

This is the implementation of SomeOtherStructWrapper:

```
public ref class SomeOtherStructWrapper
    {
    private:
    otherStruct *_ots;
    public:

    MyStructWrapper()
    {
        _ots = new otherStruct();
    }

    int AlterMyStruct(MyStructWrapper ^rto);
 }
}
```

Declaration of  AlterMyStructUnmanaged:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int AlterMyStructUnmanaged
(
    MyStruct **Object,
    otherStruct struct
);
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This question is very similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569690/passing-unmanaged-pointers-in-c-cli?rq=1
But unfortunately the function called is defined within the class and can therefore access the pointer directly.

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `AlterMyStructUnmanaged`?

Comment: Updated with C function declaration

Comment: You are pinning a structure.  That causes it to be boxed on the heap.  The boxed copy will be updated, not the original.  Just don't use pin_ptr<>.  It isn't required since it is not a managed structure on the GC heap that can move.

Comment: So when I have a property that returns the pointer, does the property return a copy of the pointer or the pointer itself?

Comment: A copy, to return the pointer itself use a reference to the pointer or a pointer to the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but your getter returns a **copy** of the pointer.

So when you use **&ptr** you are actually pointing to a copy of the original pointer so you will change the copy but not the original pointer in your myObj instance.

If you can't change the implementation of MyStructWrapper, e.g. by returning a **reference** to the pointer, you may not be able to do what you want.

Wait for the gurus to have a definitive answer...

Comment: I think you might be right... which would be disappointing. Would I be able to expose the wrapper into C# if i made the pointer a public variable?

Comment: If you're using unsafe code this should be fine if you can accept it.

Comment: In the end, I had to change the propertyto access the myStruct Pointer to return a myStruct** instead.  so it looks like

property MyStruct** Rto
{
   MyStruct** get(){pin_ptr<MyStruct*> ptr = &_rto; return ptr;}
}

Thanks all for the help!